# Изменение BackStack android

Tags: android, backstack

Здравствуйте.
В общем есть 3 Activity: A, B, C и порядок их вызова: A->B->С. Так вот, при возвращении назад из activity C нужно попадать сразу в activity A.

**UPD** Activity B не должно ложиться в BackStack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, A.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: немного не то, мне надо возвращаться из C в A по нажатию на Back (на toolbar'е либо системную кнопку) т.е., чтобы Activity B не ложилось в BackStack

Comment: @Artur, переопределите onBackPressed в С. В нем запускайте А. При нажатии на стрелку вызывайте onBackPressed

Comment: сделал почти так, как советуете, только при создании C вызывал finish() у B